# Express.js CRUD Application Cannot DELETE

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a CRUD Express.js Web Apllication. When I apply Delete method I have a 404 No Found Error.

**In app.js file**

```
var campagnes = require('./routes/campagnes');
app.use('/campagnes', campagnes);
```

**In routes/campagnes.js file**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var campagne_controller = require('../controllers/campagneController');

router.delete('/delete/:id', campagne_controller.campagne_delete);

//In Controllers/campagneController.js file 

var Campagne = require('../models/campagne');

exports.campagne_delete = function(req,res){


    Campagne.findById(req.params.id)
        .exec(function(err, row){
            if (err) {
                var errornya  = ("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
                req.flash('msg_error', errornya);
                res.redirect('/campagnes');
            }
            else
            {
                if(row == [])
                {
                    req.flash('msg_error', "Campagne can't be find!");
                    res.redirect('/campagnes');
                }
                else
                {
              // I don't delet but just change campagne status to annulee
                     row.status = 'annulee';
                    // Success - go to campagne list
                    req.flash('msg_info', 'La campagne a été marquée comme annulée');
                    res.redirect('/campagnes');
                }
            }
        });
}
```

**In views/campagne/list.jade file**

```
p.text-right
    a.text-right(href='/campagnes/delete/#{campagne._id}')
         | Annuler la campagne
hr
```

When I click on my link in list.jade view I have a 404 Not Found Error and I don't know why. I tried to find if I have a mistake in my code, but I don't see anything wrong

Comment: In else block what is value of row

Comment: Which one please ? I have two else in my code. I can't access to /campagnes/delete/#{campagne_id}  route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending request as `DELETE` method. You are using `a` tag since a tag uses GET method. You should use `ajax` call if you want `DELETE`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my link with a button like bellow :

```js
form(method='post', action='/campagnes/delete/#{campagne._id}')
   input(type="hidden",name="_method", value="DELETE")
   button.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger(type='submit', style='float: right') Annuler la campagne
br
```

And in my Controller I put this code:

```js
exports.campagne_delete = function(req,res){

    Campagne.findById(req.params.id)
        .exec(function(err, row){
            if (err) {
                var errornya  = ("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
                req.flash('msg_error', errornya);
                res.redirect('/campagnes');
            }
            else
            {

                if(row == [])
                {
                    req.flash('msg_error', "Campagne can't be find!");
                    res.redirect('/campagnes');
                }
                else
                {
                    doc = new Campagne({

                        status:'annulee',
                        _id:req.params.id

                    });

                    // Data from form is valid. Update the record.
                    Campagne.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, doc, {}, function (err, thecampagne) {
                        if (err) {
                            var errors_detail  = ("Error Update : %s ", err );
                            req.flash('msg_error', errors_detail);
                            res.redirect('/campagnes');
                        }
                    });
                    // Success - go to customer list
                    req.flash('msg_info', 'La campagne a été marquée comme annulée');
                    res.redirect('/campagnes');
                }
            }
        });
}
```